# How to add aggregate site reports in a nested multi-module project to the site of a parent multi-module project with Apache Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

**Update:** I've created a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE) [here](https://github.com/FlorianWolters/stackoverflow-76533243).

I'm currently refactoring a multi-module Apache Maven Proof-of-Concept project and have an issue regarding `reporting` plugins or the Maven Site generation.

My structure is as follows (list intent == inheritance):

- Company POM

  - Company Bills of Material (BoM)
- Aggregator POM

  - Code Project Aggregator POM (all source code projects)

    - Library JAR
    - Application JAR
  - Code Coverage Aggregator POM (a non-source code project)

The Company POM uses Convention-over-Configuration and does not define any `inherited` reports, but only "single" reports, e.g:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <reportSets>
            <reportSet>
                <reports>
                    <report>pmd</report>
                </reports>
            </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

The top-level "Aggregator POM" does not define any `reporting` plugins. It's main purpose is to aggregate and allow to separate the "source code" and "non-source code" child projects:

```
<modules>
    <module>pom/code-project-aggregator</module>
    <module>pom/code-coverage-aggregator</module>
</modules>
```

The "Code Project Aggregator POM" defines the `aggregate` reports with `<inherited>false</inherited>` and includes all source code projects as modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>../../lib/foo</module>
    <module>../../app/bar</module>
</modules>

<reporting>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
          <reportSets>
              <reportSet>
                  <id>aggregate</id>
                  <inherited>false</inherited>
                  <reports>
                      <report>aggregate-pmd</report>
                  </reports>
              </reportSet>
          </reportSets>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

The problem is, that the generated Maven Site for the top-level "Aggregator POM" does not include the reports if calling `mvn verify site-deploy`.

The reports are generated if `mvn verify site-deploy` is called for the "Code Project Aggregator POM". But I want to create the top-level site. I don't understand what is happening here: It seems that the aggregate reports are not bound to `site` if called on the top level.

Two questions:

1. Can someone explain this behavior?
2. Can someone provide the solution (or guide me into the right direction) that generates and includes the aggregate reports in the child multi-module project if calling `mvn verify site-deploy` on the top multi-module project?

I've read [Building multi-module sites](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/multimodule.html), but couldn't find any mention of issues regarding my approach.

**Update #1 2023-06-23:** I've looked at the Effective POM of "Code Project Aggregator POM" and the `aggregate` reports are included there. It seems they are simply not "triggered" if calling `mvn verify site-deploy` on the parent project.

```
<reporting>
  <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.21.0</version>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <reports>
          <report>pmd</report>
          <report>cpd</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
      <reportSet>
        <id>aggregate</id>
        <reports>
          <report>aggregate-pmd</report>
          <report>aggregate-cpd</report>
        </reports>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </plugin>
</reporting>
```

**Update #2 2023-06-23:** I was able to fix the PMD aggregate report creation by specifiying a unique `<id>` to each and every `reportSet` in the `pom.xml` files. **But:** This is **not** the complete solution, because it did not fix aggregate report creation for other plugins, e.g. Checkstyle, JXR, Surefire, Failsafe and Taglist. I took a closer look at the Effective POM and I am unable to explain this behavior. Both PMD and Checkstyle are registered for the `maven-site-plugin` below `<build>/<plugin>` in the `execution` with the ID `default-site` as a `reportPlugin`:

```
<reportPlugins>
  <reportPlugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <id>checkstyle-report</id>
        <reports>
          <report>checkstyle</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
      <reportSet>
        <id>aggregate-checkstyle-report</id>
        <reports>
          <report>checkstyle-aggregate</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </reportPlugin>
  <reportPlugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.21.0</version>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <id>pmd-report</id>
        <reports>
          <report>pmd</report>
          <report>cpd</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
      <reportSet>
        <id>aggregate-pmd-report</id>
        <reports>
          <report>aggregate-pmd</report>
          <report>aggregate-cpd</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </reportPlugin>
</reportPlugins>
```

**Update 3 2023-06-26:** I've created a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE) as a [Git repository on GitHub](https://github.com/FlorianWolters/stackoverflow-76533243).

Comment: I do think it is impossible because the `aggregate` reports have to be declared on the same level on which the `mvn site site:stage` command is executed, in order to make it work. Note that this does **not** prevent one to add additional multi-module projects below the Aggregate POM (which is on the top-level, but below the Company POM). By doing this, I got the directory structure I wanted, but also the POM inheritance structure I wanted. I do not know, if this costs runtime penalties during Maven Site generation. So far, I did not observe any duplicate (unwanted) reports in the output.